# Continuous non-differentable functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions

I'm looking for some examples of everywhere continuous functions which are nowhere differentable. I found already Takagi curve and Weierstrass function. Can you point out some online courses or pdf docs?
It will be really helpful for me because I'm going to write a bachelor thesis about it.

Comment: Try the google search ["nowhere differentiable" + continuous + thesis](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nowhere+differentiable%22+continuous+thesis). The top hit when I did this is [Johan Thim's 2003 Master Thesis](https://pure.ltu.se/ws/files/30923977/LTU-EX-03320-SE.pdf) that is frequently cited in math stackexchange.

Comment: See also my answers to [Who first drew the Weierstrass function?](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/who-first-drew-the-weierstrass-function) **AND** [Smallest positive zero of Weierstrass nowhere differentiable function](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/160395/smallest-positive-zero-of-weierstrass-nowhere-differentiable-function) **AND** [Level sets of a Weierstrass nowhere-differentiable function](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/160184/level-sets-of-a-weierstrass-nowhere-differentiable-function)